# A way to insert text to the top of each source file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way, in VS2010, to insert a piece of text at the top of each source file; for example, a copyright notice?

Answer (score 1):

You can amend the default template for a class to add your own header.

Search for a file called `class.zip` in your Visual Studio directory in Program Files (easier to search because the full path depends on your Visual Studio edition and which language you are using).

Inside it there is a .cs file which is the default template.

I don't know of any way to run through the existing files to add the header, although that could probably be easily achieved with a Powershell command.